# Singleton Variable Prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to create a rule in Prolog that defines daughter_of and son_of in my database as follows. However I am getting a singleton error, with Y, M, and F in the new rules. I thought this only came up if the variables have not been used elsewhere?  Also is this the right way to write the new rules?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

```
male(albert).
male(edward).

female(alice).
female(victoria).

parents(edward, victoria, albert).
parents(alice, victoria, albert).

sister_of(X,Y):-
female(X),
parents(X,M,F),
parents(Y,M,F).

brother_of(X,Y):-
male(X),
parents(X,M,F),
parents(Y,M,F).

daughter_of(X,Y):-
female(X),
parents(X,M,F).

son_of(X,_Y):-
male(X),
parents(X,M,F).
```

Comment: The scope of a variable in a predicate is limited to the specific clause. So if a variable is only mentioned once in a clause, you'll see the singleton warning. Your `son_of` and `daughter_of` predicates are only one clause each and each of these mention `M` but don't use them. `daughter_of` isn't using `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get mother and father with `parents(X,M,F)` you forgot to check if mother or father = Y.

Here is corrected code:

```
daughter_of(X,Y):-
    female(X),
    parents(X,M,F),
    (Y = M ; Y = F).

son_of(X,Y):-
    male(X),
    parents(X,M,F),
    (Y = M ; Y = F).
```

Test run:

```
?- son_of(X, Y).
X = edward,
Y = victoria ;
X = edward,
Y = albert.

?- daughter_of(X, Y).
X = alice,
Y = victoria ;
X = alice,
Y = albert ;
false.
```